# Retrieving Values for each line in Textarea Box

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So I've came across an issue that I'm having regarding a textarea. My goal is to have a form with a textarea where a user can enter an alphanumeric name line by line and then it would pull that information from a database and display it into a table.

For example:

```
tt1
tt2
tt3
```

and on submit it would return all of the data associated with those 3 names.

I can get the textarea, parse it and get the raw values to be inserted into the sql query, but I'm getting stuck at outputting the results.

My code for now is as follows:

index.html

```
    <form method="POST" action="getreport.php">



      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textarea">Textarea</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="textarea" id="textarea" class="textarea" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
      </div>



      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

getreport.php

```
    <?php

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "server";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $text = trim($_POST['textarea']);
        $textAr = preg_split('/[\n\r]+/', $text);   //<--- preg_split is where the magic happens
        $textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind

        foreach ($textAr as $line) {
            // processing here. 
            $sql = "SELECT * from guestlist WHERE guestname='$line'";
            echo "$sql";  //just checking query output for now
        } 



        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    //<---- take this while loop out


                echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">'; 
                echo "<tr><th>Hostname</th><th>Guestname:</th><th>date</th><th>owner</th></tr>"; 
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                  echo "<tr><td>"; 
                  echo $row['hostname'];
                  echo "</td><td>";   
                  echo $row['guestname'];
                  echo "</td><td>";    
                  echo $row['date'];
                  echo "</td><td>";   
                  echo $row['owner'];
                  echo "</td></tr>";  
                }
                echo "</table>";
            }    //<-----as well as the closing bracket
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        $conn->close();



    ?>
```

Any help or guidance on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't build your raw SQL query like that, it is vulnerable to SQL injections. Use prepared statements.

Comment: @le_m Good point. I should prepare and bind them. This way we are telling mysql what type of data to expect. This is being done on a local server of mine for fun to see if it can be done, but I should definitely get in the habit now regardless. Thanks for that. I'll go back and fix it on my end.

Comment: With help from the other members, I have managed to solve this. Being that I have not come across something like this from other posts, I updated my original code and posted the correct for solution for others who might have the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure your approach to the problem is the correct one, and also as someone suggested you should be worried about SQL injection. Said that, this could be one solution:

```
    $text = trim($_POST['textarea']);
    $textAr = str_replace("/n",",", $text);
    $sql = "SELECT * from guestlist WHERE FIND_IN_SET(guestname,'$line')>0";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Another way could be just iteratin every time

```
 <?php

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "server";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $text = trim($_POST['textarea']);
        $textAr = explode("/n", $text);
        $textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind

        foreach ($textAr as $line) {
            // processing here. 
            $sql = "SELECT * from guestlist WHERE guestname='$line'";
            echo "$sql";  //just checking query output for now

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
   // <---------------- ITERATE INSIDE THE FOREACH
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


                echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">'; 
                echo "<tr><th>Hostname</th><th>Guestname:</th><th>date</th><th>owner</th></tr>"; 
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                  echo "<tr><td>"; 
                  echo $row['hostname'];
                  echo "</td><td>";   
                  echo $row['guestname'];
                  echo "</td><td>";    
                  echo $row['date'];
                  echo "</td><td>";   
                  echo $row['owner'];
                  echo "</td></tr>";  
                }
                echo "</table>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

        } // Close the foreach



        $conn->close();



    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @Ivan G. I tried this out and it still isn't working 100%.  Basically line 1's value should be put into the variable in the query and printed to the table and so on and so forth for the other line members. 
That's how I envisioned it to be at least when the query executed and prints the table, but my main problem is it just won't print the table right despite parsing the lines to their own value separately. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you used 2 while loops - fetch_assoc and mysqli_fetch_array? Each call here moves the pointer to the next row. Maybe that's why your table is not displaying correct data? It seems you can remove the fetch_assoc loop.

Comment: thanks @phpd Your comment helped me realized that I did have 2 while loops where the one wasn't needed. Can't believe I overlooked that. Anyway, I used your advice and took it out and modified my code a bit to make it all come together and now it's working! thanks